# How to use jq streaming for processing large array of objects and convert into array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, linux, stream, jq

I have a verge large file, 24 GB which consists an array of 22M JSON objects. I have to do some manipulation for each JSON object and write into another file. I am using below command

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' test.json \
| jq -c ' if has ("middleName") then .sortableMiddleName=.middleName else . end | if has("middleName") then .middleName=[.middleName] else . end' \
> test_new.json
```

The command works without any issues but the output contains JSON objects separated by new line and there is no parent array. For eg initially, the structure of file was like below

```
[

object 1,
object 2,
........,
.........

]
```

After processing the file, the structure of output file was like below.

```
object 1

object 2

........

........
```

Here there are no array brackets plus each object is separated by new line. I want to convert it into original structure with an array consists of objects separated by comma without affecting memory

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The following response may be of interest in the case (contrary to the specifics of this particular question)
that the output array is small enough to fit into memory.

One option would be to change the second invocation of jq to this form:

```
jq -nc '[inputs | .... ]'
```

The -n option here goes with `inputs`, and the outer square brackets put everything into an array.

Another possibility, again based on the above assumption, might be to combine the two calls to jq into one:

```
< data.json jq -cn --stream '
  [fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
   | if has ("middleName") then .sortableMiddleName=.middleName 
     else . end
     | if has("middleName") then .middleName=[.middleName] 
       else . end ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to invoke jq twice, but because the output array is going to be so large, your best bet is probably to convert your stream of objects to a JSON array in a funky way, e.g.

```
echo '['
< data.json jq -nr --stream '
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
  | (if has ("middleName") then .sortableMiddleName=.middleName 
     else . end
     | if has("middleName") then .middleName=[.middleName] 
       else . end), ","' | sed '$d'
echo ']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the "[JSON Machine"](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine) library, there's a simple and relatively fast solution to the original problem that avoids the disadvantages (*) of jq's streaming parser (jq --stream), though it does entail installing more software.

To make it trivial to use, I wrote a script named `jm` (which can be found [here](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq)).  A solution can then be derived from one of the other solutions on this page by simply calling `jm` to create a stream of the top-level objects. For example:

```
jm data.json | jq '
  (if has ("middleName") then .sortableMiddleName=.middleName 
   else . end
  | if has("middleName") then .middleName=[.middleName] 
    else . end), ","' | sed '$d'; echo ']'
```

---

(*) The main disadvantages being slowness and obscurity.